# Probabilistic selection algorithm

Tags: algorithm

Given is:

- An array of length `N`.
- The array contains integers.
- The integers are not necessarily sorted.

Find an algorithm that:

- Returns (a close approximation of)the `K`-th smallest array element.
- Has a runtime complexity of O(`N` log `N`) and a space complexity of O(log `N`).
- The algorithm needn't be deterministic. In case of a probabilistic algorithm also provide a measure for the quality of the approximated result.

Comment: Please add more information. What's the "selection algorithm" being modified?  Also, if it's homework you should tag it as such.

Comment: Selection algorithm is an algorithm to select kth order element in an array without sorting it.

Comment: @Algos - is this homework?  (If it is, then I'm sure that the *point* of it is to get you to work the answer out for yourself.)

Comment: yes its a homework.. stuck thr for a long time .. so I was looking for some hint .

Comment: My first idea is that it isn't possible. All selection algorithms I can think of either require write access to the array or `O(n)` space. I hope to be proven wrong overnight though.

Comment: Good question, but this algorithm seems like it could take hours to write. fkdat xD

Comment: I think a hint is that the number of bits a key requires is O(log(n)).

Comment: Is the algorithm required to be O(n lg n) in the worst case or just average case?  I can see a fairly easy way to do it for average case, but don't know a worst case one off hand.

Comment: @jswolf I''m a third party to this conversation, I'm not entirely sure what your statement about "bits a key requires" has to do with selection algorithm.

Comment: we need a randomized algorithm with O (n log n ) time in high probability

Comment: @Algos: I see how to do it now.  How much detail do you want?

Comment: @glowcoder, You're allowed `O(log(n)` space, which is conveniently the size of the keys into your readonly array. So you can store some constant number of keys.

Comment: @Jeremiah, 
May be an example will suffice.. :)

Comment: @Moron – Pick the pivot point at random to make it randomized.

Comment: Umm, randomized Quicksort does this just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Treat the problem as something analogous to Quicksort.  Given an element in the array, you can get its rank in O(n) time and O(lg n) space.  You can use binary search to find an element with a given rank in O(lg n) iterations of that, for a total of O(lg n) space and O(n lg n) time.

Comment: How to get rank of an element in O(n) in case of read only ?. the problem is to get the rank of an element in (n log n ) time.

Comment: @Algos: You can get the rank of a given element in O(n); getting an element with a given rank is what we are trying to solve.

Comment: yep .. got that .. can you explain further the algorithm. still somewhat confused.

Comment: @Algos:  Assume rank 0 is the smallest array element.  Get the largest and smallest elements of the array (call them `lo` and `hi`) and their ranks (`lo_rank` and `hi_rank`).  Label *A*: Then, pick some element `m` between `lo` and `hi` (in O(n) time) and compute its rank `m_rank` (in O(n)).  If `m_rank == k`, we are done.  If `m_rank < k`, replace `lo` and `lo_rank` with `m` and `m_rank` respectively and go to *A*; if `m_rank > k`, do the same with `hi` and go to *A*.

Comment: by rank do you mean thr index ?? min element will have rank 0 & max with rank n.

Comment: @Algos: No, I mean rank, with the definitions you show (`0` and `n` are the limits on ranks, and you search for elements with ranks between those).

Comment: am not clear on how to recurse if m_rank<> k.
can you give an example

Comment: @Algos: There is a loop in the code (the label *A* in the comment above).  You start `lo` and `hi` with the limits of the array (min and max elements), then iteratively shrink the range until you find the correct element.  Thus, `lo` gets progressively larger and `hi` gets smaller.

Comment: How do you propose you find an element with the given rank in `O(log n)` space and without modifying the array?

Comment: To clarify: this seems to be what @Dave has posted. Is this free from the infinite loop problem his code has?

Comment: @IVlad: Finding an element with a given rank is the goal of the whole algorithm, and finding the rank of a given element is a subroutine that we are going to use.  Could you also read the comments to @aaz's answer?  Those give a lot of explanation of the algorithm too.

Comment: I have read them, and I don't think this follows the requirements. The run time is `O(n log v)`, where `v = largest of array - smallest of array`.

Comment: @IVlad: OK -- I saw that they were doing bisection on the elements, but didn't realize what that would do to the complexity.  The version I posted does bisection on ranks instead, so it doesn't have this problem (since those are always between 0 and n).

Answer (score 2):

Don't construct partitions. Describe what the partitions are (in constant space), and recursively select on this.

Each subarray that quickselect recurses into can be described by its bounds (min and max element values, not their indexes). Iterating over a subarray so described requires O(*n*) comparisons, which are made at every recursion level, up to the same depth as in quicksort: O(log *n*) in the average case.

Quicksort also makes O(*n*) comparisons at every recursion level, while ordinary permuting quickselect makes O(*n*) comparisons in total in the average case (because it always recurses into only one partition).

Here's a [sample implementation](http://althenia.net/svn/stackoverflow/constselect.py) for distinct elements with an ordinary quickselect implementation for comparison.

Comment: How do you describe the partitions in O(logn) space? Say the numbers less than a given element are the 1st element, 7th element, 15, .., 567991th etc.

Comment: @Moron – You want O(1) per iteration. "Numbers less than a given element."

Comment: I still don't get it. Say you pick one element, find that it's position is 100. Now how do you recurse? How would you know what to recurse on? How would you describe all the relevant elements?

Comment: @Moron – You recurse on all the elements less than the one at rank 100. Say you then find one at rank 50. You recurse on all the elements between the one ranked 50 and the one ranked 100. Iteration, instead of being free, now uses 2*n comparisons per recursion.

Comment: I think @Jeremiah has the same idea in his answer.

Comment: Recurse? How? Again, how do you determine which elements to take!

Comment: @Moron – You describe the array you are working on by its bounds: lowest and highest element. So instead of passing `array[k]` into each iteration, you pass `(array[n], lo, hi)`, where there are `k` elements in `array[n]` with value `lo ≤ x ≤ hi`. `array[n]` is always the original array, so it's just a pointer. Iterating over the elements that would have been in `array[k]` takes `2*n` comparisons against `lo` and `hi`. Pivoting is now notional, as you don't actually construct `array[k]` for the next step, you just find its size and bounds.

Comment: The array is read-only and cannot be rearranged. It could be unsorted in the beginning. The assumption that you can reduce to contiguous sub-array is incorrect (the example I gave in the first comment).

Comment: @Moron – That's not my assumption, and I don't need a contiguous subarray. `lo` and `hi` are element _values_. I will iterate over all `n` elements of the original array in each step, but I will ignore those `x` that don't satisfy `lo ≤ x ≤ hi`.

Comment: @aaz: I see. Do you have a proof that it runs in O(Nlogn) with high probability?

Comment: @Moron – Only an intuitive one. Randomized quickselect uses O(_n_) comparisons per step and recurses an expected O(log _n_) times, giving O(_n_ log _n_) runtime. This uses an extra 2 _n_ comparisons per step and recurses exactly like quickselect, so it's still O(_n_ log _n_).

Comment: @aaz: Randomized Select is expected O(n). I believe the proof of that relies on reducing the size (by actual partitioning). It does look to me too that the expected number of pivots can be shown to be O(logn). But that still does not show high probability I think. For high probability we would likely need to show o(logn) (note small o).

Comment: btw, I believe we can show Randomized select (which allows rearrangement) to be O(n logn) with high probability using Markov's inequality.

Comment: To clarify: When I say Randomized select i refer to the standard randomized algorithm for selection which allows re-arrangement and can be shown to take expect O(n) comparisons. The number of pivots chosen in that algorithm and in your algorithm follows the same distribution...

Comment: @Moron – You're right. I was thinking that quickselect performs the same as quicksort (expected O(_n_ log _n_) comparisons). So my algorithm uses more comparisons than quickselect, but approximately the same number of comparisons as quicksort, which [Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Randomized_quicksort_expected_complexity)  is expected O(_n_ log _n_). Maybe "with high probability" from the question means "low probability of worst-case behaviour"? Also my algorithm uses only constant space (one recursion which is a tail call), so it's probably not the required answer.

Comment: @aaz: With high probability means the probability of running in O(nlogn) time tends to 1 as n tends to infinity, so that is a stronger statement than saying the expect running time is O(nlogn). Technically you are using O(logn) space, as to even store n, you require log n bits. I have a feeling that this is algorithm is correct. Only the proof is missing.

Comment: @Moron – Yep, depth in quicksort is bounded with high probability ([1](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15499-s09/www/scribe/lec7/lec7.pdf), [2](http://valis.cs.uiuc.edu/~sariel/teach/notes/algos/lec/10_rand_II.pdf), [3](http://www8.cs.umu.se/kurser/TDBC91/VT02/lec8.html)). The proof here is even slightly simpler, because there is only one recursion path, unlike quicksort, which must recurse into every partition.

Comment: @aaz: I am not sure we can use the quicksort analysis without modifications, though. There is a difference. For instance, in quicksort if we find a pivot p, and elements q and r such that q < p < r, then we will never compare q and r. But that is not the case in this algorithm, as we never rearrange the array. In fact, I believe the analysis of this algorithm might actually be simpler than that of Quicksort! Also, the depth probability bound is 1/n is your link 1. The others seem to estimate different things...

Answer (score 2):

1. Iterate over the array once to find the `minimum` and `maximum` element.
2. Iterate over the array to find a random element `pivot` between `minimum` and `maximum` (exclusive).
3. Iterate over the array and count the number of elements less than or equal to `pivot` (`numSmallerEqual`) and the number of elements greater than `pivot` (`numBigger`).

   1. If K <= `numSmallerEqual`, set `maximum`=pivot.
   2. Else set `minimum`=pivot.
4. If (`maximum` - `minimum`)==0, output `minimum`, terminate.
5. If (`maximum` - `minimum`)==1

   1. If K <= `numSmallerEqual`, output `minimum`.
   2. Else output `maximum`.
   3. Terminate.
6. GOTO 2:

EDIT: Corrected the error pointed out by lVlad, still not tested.

Comment: This in fact does not require O(lg n) space as restrained, but O(1). Very nice!

Comment: Except it's wrong. `1 3, k = 2. pivot = 2, minimum = 1, maximum = 3, numSmallerEqual = 1, minimum = 2. pivot = 2, numSmallerEqual = 1, minimum = 2` ... infinite loop.

Comment: @Dave - I would have suggested a fix if I had one. I'm not sure how to avoid the infinite loop.

Comment: I haven't given a lot of thought to the correctness of your updated algorithm, but it's worth pointing out that it doesn't really follow the requirements. The complexity is `O(n log v)`, where `v` is the difference between the maximum and minimum values of the array, not `O(n log n)`. `v` can be independent of `n`.

Comment: Why did you change the question?

Comment: @DAve: You changed it :-) Earlier we required to return the correct value, but the run time was O(nlogn) _with high probability_ (and so Omega(n^2) was allowed on some inputs). You have turned it into an approximation algorithm with guaranteed O(nlogn) worst case time.

Comment: And I don't remember the question specifying that the array contains integers. It could contain apples and oranges as long as there was an order relation between them.

Comment: @Moron The original statement was quite hard to understand and I tried to make it more clear taking into account all the information from the comments. I then *proposed* an edit, which got *accepted*. In the case that it's inappropriate I'm sorry and please feel free to reverse it.

Comment: @Dave: Yeah, OP(Algos) has a knack for making the wording of the question (and title) pathetic :-) Thanks for trying to correct. In fact, the first version of the question did not even talk about a randomized algorithm! Any requests for the version as given by the professor were also ignored. So, if anyone makes an edit, it won't be me...

Comment: @IVlad, @Dave, @Moron: I just did an edit on the post to fix the complexity issue, and removed the note about it.  It also removes the need to be able to do arithmetic on the values in the array.

Comment: @Jeremiah cool, what is the probability that this will find the correct element after log N iterations - or - what is the mean squared error of the returned element after log N iterations?

Comment: @Dave: This algorithm always returns the correct element, but its iteration count is log N only in expectation; the worst case is N iterations.  Did you need an algorithm that got the approximate right answer with a bounded worst-case time instead?

Comment: @Jeremiah I don't anything :-), Algos does. I still would be interested in the second analysis.

Comment: @Dave: I do not know a way off-hand to find an approximate answer in a bounded time; stopping the algorithm given after O(lg N) loop iterations would probably work, but I don't know what its error rate would be.  Its worst case would be really bad, though (stopping after `j` iterations, you could get the `j`-th highest or lowest element regardless of what the goal rank was).

Answer (score 0):

You can take the parameterization approach:

Since we have `k` specified in the problem, we can treat it as a constant, thus space of O(`k` log `N`) should be acceptable.

1. Divide the array into `k` partitions of equal length (O(1) time and O(`k` log `N`) space to store the partition borders because each key should only require log `N` space)
2. Find the smallest element in each partition (O(`N`) time and O(`k` log `N`) space to store the smallest elements
3. return the max of the k elements you have (O(`k`) time)

Since there's room for more cycles in there, there's probably a better way to do it. Also note that this would perform very poorly on an array that is sorted...